# Laravel eloquent relationship between two relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I hope you get my point on my title hehe. Here's what I want to achieve.

I have **User** model that have relationship from **Roles** and **Permissions**.
Here's the code:

```
class User extends Model {

     ....

     public function roles() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Roles');
     }


     public function permissions() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permissions');
     }

}
```

and that work's fine but I want to have another function like this

```
    ....

    public function permissions_by_roles() {

    }

    ....
```

Because each user has individual permissions and permissions that is being inherited from roles. I want to get the list of user's permissions depending on user's roles. How can I achieve this? Here's my tables:

```
users
roles
permissions
role_user - contains all roles of each user(ex. admin, super admin, user)
permission_user - contains all permissions of each user (ex. edit, delete)
permission_role  - contains all permissions for each roles.
```

I hope anyone can help me. Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship in combination with a merging where necessary:

```
class User extends Model {

     ....

     public function roles() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Roles');
     }


     public function permissions() {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Permissions');
     }

     public function inheritedPermissions() {
         return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Permissions', 'App\Models\Roles');
     }    
}
```

Then if you want all user permissions you can do:

```
 $user = User::with(["permissions", "inheritedPermissions"])->where("id", $id)->first();
```

All permissions will be:

```
$allPermissions = $user->permissions->merge($user->inheritedPermissions)->unique("id");
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for! you save me hehe thanks a lot!!

Comment: @aiipee If user specific permissions are the exception rather than the rule then an alternative to what you're doing is to drop the `permission_user` table completely and when you need to add specific permissions to a single user just create a new role called something like `UserXPermissionRole` and grant that role only to user X. If you do this you can drop the `permissions` relationship as well and keep only the `inheritedPermission`

Comment: what a nice idea! I will do this, thank you very much for your suggestion! :)

Comment: Appreciated much! Thanks for the help, i hope you could also help me with my future concerns regarding laravel hehe! Thanks!